# How to put for loop to a separate thread

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have for loop that can read up to 100k rows.
When I start this function it block my UI until its done.

```
for (Item* sp in items){
    data = [data stringByAppendingFormat:@"\"%@\",\"%@\","\n", ....];
}
```

How can I put this to separate thread so it doesn't block UI?

Comment: When you say "read up to 100k rows", what do you mean?  I don't see any reading.

Comment: That sort of depends what you are doing with the `data` variable after you are done. Do you display it in the UI? Is there something waiting for it?

Comment: I would suggest you to use blocks.

Comment: There can be 100k items. I use foreach loop to create CSV string that I send later to web service. I decided to use CSV as it produce smaller file. So I am looking the fastest way to make this and I thought that if I put it on separate thread that it will work faster and don't block UI.

Comment: I'm kind of old school, but I'd just use performSelectorInBackground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you've provided a complete example, but the simple use of [Grand Central Dispatch](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html) should do the trick:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    for (Item* sp in items){
        data = [data stringByAppendingFormat:@"\"%@\",\"%@\","\n", ....];
    }

    // Then if you want to "display" the data (i.e. send it to any UI-element):
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.someControl.data = data;
    });

    // else simply send the data to a web service:
    self.webService.data = data;
    [self.webService doYourThing];

});
```

Comment: I have explained it better in comment in question.

Answer (score 0):

This may suits you

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{

        for(Item* sp in items)
        {
            data = [data stringByAppendingFormat:@"\"%@\",\"%@\","\n", ....];
        }

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            //UI updates using item data 

            });


    });
```

Comment: Dispatch to main *inside* the loop? That probably going to be some overhead there.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to use NSInvocationOperation.

```
NSOperationQueue *OperationQueue=[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
NSInvocationOperation *SubOperation=[[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(LoopOperation) object:nil];

[SubOperation setQueuePriority:NSOperationQueuePriorityVeryHigh]; //You can also set the priority of that thread.
[OperationQueue addOperation:SubOperation];


-(void)LoopOperation
{
    for (Item* sp in items)
    {
        data = [data stringByAppendingFormat:@"\"%@\",\"%@\","\n", ....];
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        //UI updates using item data 

        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If order doesn't matter in your loop I prefer to use `dispatch_apply()` inside of `dispatch_async()`. The difference is that a traditional `for(...)` loop will put all of the work on a single thread, while `dispatch_apply()` will perform the individual iterations in parallel on multiple threads, but as a whole the loop is synchronous, where the loop will not exit until all of the processing is complete.

A good test to see if order matters in your loop is whether the loop can be performed backwards with the same results.